# Reverse string without reverse function

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

For an input text I have to count all the vowels, capitalize first letter in each word and output text in reverse(doesn't have to be capitalized), without using title or reverse functions. I was able to figure out the count for vowels, but struggling with other two.

```
def main():

    vowelCount = 0
    text = 'abc'

    while(len(text) != 0):
        text = input('Please etner some text or press <ENTER> to exit: ')

        for char in text:
            if char in 'aeiouAEIOU':
                vowelCount += 1
        print('Vowels:', vowelCount)
        vowelCount = 0



        for i in text:
            i = text.find('') + 1
        print(i)

        print(text[0].upper() + text[1:])


main()
```

Comment: The words in reverse or every character in reverse?

Comment: [Reversing a string is already covered in great detail.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/931092/364696)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two examples of reversing a string.
Slice the string

```
>>> s = 'hello'
>>> reversed_s = s[::-1]
```

Or with a loop.

```
res = ''
for char in s:
    res = char + res
```

---

Full Code

```
def main():
    # Run infinitely until break or return
    # it's more elegant to do a while loop this way with a condition to
    # break instead of setting an initial variable with random value.
    while True:
        text = input('Please enter some text or press <ENTER> to exit: ')
        # if nothing is entered then break
        if not text:
            break

        vowelCount = 0
        res = ''
        prev_letter = None

        for char in text:
            if char.lower() in 'aeiou':
                vowelCount += 1
            # If previous letter was a space or it is the first letter
            # then capitalise it.
            if prev_letter == ' ' or prev_letter is None:
                char = char.upper()

            res += char # add char to result string
            prev_letter = char # update prev_letter

        print(res) # capitalised string
        print(res[::-1]) # reverse the string
        print('Vowel Count is: {0}'.format(vowelCount))

# Example
Please enter some text or press <ENTER> to exit: hello world!
Hello World!
!dlroW olleH
Vowel Count is: 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip man, but how would you capitalize each word using the loop without reversing the string.

Comment: @MrG Updated answer. I've split it so the resulting string is not constructed in reverse and instead reverse at the end using first method suggested (Slicing)